# how to get data from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

hey guys may i know how to get data from controller ?

for example

**controller.js**

```
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.form = {};
  $scope.submitPost = function() {
    $http.post('/register', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      });
  };

}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
app.post('/register', sessionHandler.handleSignup);
```

**routes/session.js**

```
 this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
     // when i try to access into the controller by using "data" it said my "data" 
     // is not declare, what should i pass into `var data` = ?? in order to
     // access the data from controller 

        var email = data.email,
         confirmEmail = data.confirmEmail,
         password = data.password,
         confirmPassword = data.confirmPassword,
         firstName = data.firstName,
         lastName = data.lastName,
         penName = data.penName,
         publicUsername = data.publicUsername;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `express.urlencoded()` and `express.json()` [middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) in order to parse body data that was sent via `HTTP` `DELETE` / `POST` / `PUT`.

After that, there will be a `body` property on the `req` object and you can use it like that:

```
this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
    "use strict";

    var data = req.body,
        email = data.confirmEmail,
        // etc.
};
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, do i have to include this 3 middleware in my app ? app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json())

Answer (score 0):

from the success response in your http post you could just assign a scope to it then display it to your partials. Something like this.

```
$http.post('/register', $scope.form).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
```

Then from your partials/view

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

Regards,

Comment: hi thanks for reply,i need to pass the data into a function to perform validation after that insert into database rather than display it.